# Check if query string is SELECT or other type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, laravel

I have a page where admins enter their own custom query, just for extra safety measures i want to disallow using any queries other than "SELECT" query.

How would i check if the query is SELECT or DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT ... , including detecting tricks like SELECT INTO.

I'm using Laravel framework, it has the function

```
DB::select($query);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't check if it is a select statement or something else.

Comment: What have you done till now? I want to see your basic working in-order to suggest you further.

Comment: You should make an array with the disallowed words like Delete, Update, Insert, then, inside a foreach loop check your query for these words. If it contains one of these, die();

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala i haven't decided which way is the best to go, if there was no other way i will just add "blocked keywords"

Comment: Check this [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-sql-parser/)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my proposal about how to detect if a SQL statement is indeed a SELECT one (note that PHP 7's type hinting is used):

```
function isSelect(string $stmt): bool {

    // Default trim()'s mask plus left parentheses
    $_TRIM_MASK_WITH_PAREN = "( \t\n\r\0\x0B";

    return 'SELECT' === strtoupper(
        substr(
            ltrim($stmt, $_TRIM_MASK_WITH_PAREN), 0, 6
        )
    );
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Keep in mind, thats check ignore comments is mysql query, like: /* comment */ SELECT id, question
    FROM desdf
    WHERE col1 = 2
    LIMIT 1

Comment: To trim sql comment just add: 

    $stmt = preg_replace('@(--[^\r\n]*)|(\#[^\r\n]*)|(/\*[\w\W]*?(?=\*/)\*/)@ms', '', $stmt ); 
before func body code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be the safest to use a special DB user for this, and set the user right in a way, that he can only do SELECT and not modify the DB, if this is also an option for you, it will be much safer.

Comment: It's a great idea but not practical for my case - would be a hassle to let each one creates an another database user

Comment: I actually did not mean EVERYone should have another user. Just in your PHP code, use a different SQL user for you DB connection. The user in the frontend will not see any difference. And you have to set up only 1 read-only user for this purpose

Comment: Yah that's what i understood, but i meant the software will have multiple installations, on different servers

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (stripos($query, "select") !== false && stripos($query, "from") !== false) {
   DB::select($query);
}
```

Comment: Your checks may easily let pass, for instance, some update query with an inner select on it.

Answer (score -1):

Not the right way but this will do the tricks :

```
<?php

$qry="SELECT * FROM table";

$qry_array=explode(" ",$qry);

echo "Type of query :".$qry_array[0]; //SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE
```

Comment: This will fail if for some reason the query starts with a parenthesis. You may end up having something like "(" or "(SELECT" in that first position.

Comment: @DanielM As i clearly said, its just a trick not the solution! and if u bother about "(SELECT" then you can replace it using str_replace..

Comment: You cant just downvote answer if you have no proper solution or a reason. You can update the answer if you want to improve the answer.

Comment: My last goal is to start a discussion here, but your answer does not provide a valid solution. Anyone attempting to make use of it may easily turn into troubles. On the other hand, improve the "trick" is quite straightforward: simply "trim" the query to avoid starting spaces and parenthesis.